# Check for expired date in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm fairly new to programming and adjusting some code already written for me. I would like to check if a date in a Gridview(named: playDate) is older than the current date and if so the registration page icon will have it's visibility set to false.

But I'm getting the error:

```
BC30311: Value of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' cannot be converted to 'Date'
```

The error appears to be on this line:

```
playDate = r.Cells(1).FindControl("playDate")
```

Here's the Front end code:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSCompetitions" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT tblCompetitions.compID, tblCompetitions.compName, tblCompetitions.playDate, tblCompetitions.venue, tblCompetitions.entryPrice, tblCompetitions.rules, tblCompetitions.maxPlayers
        FROM tblCompetitions                

        ORDER BY tblCompetitions.playDate DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Gridview ID="gdvCompetitions" width="100%"  runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="compID" DataSourceID="DSCompetitions" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">

            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="compName" HeaderText="Event" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="playDate" DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderText="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="venue" HeaderText="Venue" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="entryPrice" HeaderText="Entry Fee £" />

                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypView" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/competition-view.aspx?compID=" & Eval("compID").ToString & "&round=1" %>'><asp:Image ID="ImgView" Width="30px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/view-icon.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypBook" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/competition-book.aspx?compID=" & Eval("compID").ToString %>'><asp:Image ID="ImgRegister" Width="30px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/register-icon.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here's My VB Code:

```
For Each r As GridViewRow in gdvCompetitions.Rows
    If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then 'Execute the code only for datarow, excluding footer and header
        Dim playDate As Date
        playDate = r.Cells(1).FindControl("playDate") 
        Dim hypBook As Hyperlink
        hypBook = r.Cells(5).FindControl("hypBook") 
        If date.now > playDate Then 
            hypBook.visible=false
        End If
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: You defined `playDate` as `Date` then initiated it with Control by `playDate = r.Cells(1).FindControl("playDate") `, it is not correct.

Comment: change it to `playDate = r.Cells(1).Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `playDate` as Date then initiated it with Control by `playDate = r.Cells(1).FindControl("playDate")` , it is not correct.

`FindControl` will find a control, as you know we can't initiate `datetime` variable with ASP.Net controls so 
Change your code to :

```
For Each r As GridViewRow in gdvCompetitions.Rows
    If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then 'Execute the code only for datarow, excluding footer and header
        Dim playDate As Date
        playDate = Convert.ToDateTime(r.Cells(1).Text)
        Dim hypBook As Hyperlink
        hypBook = r.Cells(5).FindControl("hypBook") 
        If date.now > playDate Then 
            hypBook.visible=false
        End If
    End If
Next r
```

I am not VB.Net programmer, But I am sure my explanation are right and changed code also works.

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take the value of your control, attempt to convert it to a date ("attempt" because you never know if a non-date could make its way into this column), and then do the comparison.

```
var playDate = DateTime.Parse(r.Cells(1).Text); // this could throw an error, research DateTime.TryParse()
if (DateTime.Now > playDate)
{
   // then...
}
```

Sorry. Just realized your question is VB. [Telerik's code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) is amazing for going from C# to VB, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
playDate = r.Cells(1).FindControl("playDate")
```

Use

```
playDate = r.Cells(1).Text;
```

`FindControl` will only work if you have any asp control in grid. For boundfield, you need to get the value of cell.